# conversion error with enum in bit OR

Tags: c++11, gcc, enums, bit

I have this code which fails to compile with gcc 4.9.2:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum fooEnum
{
    foo1 = 1 << 0,
    foo2 = 1 << 1,
    foo3 = 1 << 2,
};

int main()
{
        fooEnum foo {};
        int bar;

        bar = foo1;
        foo |= (fooEnum) bar; // fails

        printf("foo=%d\n", foo);
}
```

Compile command: `gcc -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror enum.cpp -c`

The error message is:

```
enum.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
enum.cpp:16:6: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘fooEnum’ [-fpermissive]
  foo |= (fooEnum) bar;
      ^
```

Changing the line to

```
    foo = (fooEnum) bar;
```

works fine. Why I cannot use the bit OR? As you can see `fooEnum` is a `bit enum`.

**UPDATE:**

Changing the code to

```
    fooEnum foo = foo2;
    int bar;

    bar = foo1 | foo;
    foo = (fooEnum) bar;
```

works and the output is `3` as it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line:

```
foo |= (fooEnum) bar;
```

is equivalent to:

```
foo = foo | (fooEnum) bar;
```

The bitwise OR operator causes its arguments to be treated as `int` types (via the integer promotion rules). Therefore, the right side of the assignment evaluates to a value of type `int`. This cannot be directly assigned to the `fooEnum` instance `foo`, and therefore the compiler flags an error.

Comment: Yes, changing it to `foo = (fooEnum) (foo | (fooEnum) bar);` works.